# Custom kernel filter for texture lookup in OpenGL. Is it possible?

Tags: opengl

I would like to experiment with a sub-pixel rendering technique described in this [page](https://www.grc.com/cttech.htm).

The idea (in case you don't have the time to read the whole thing), is to take advantage of the fact that each pixel of an LCD has in fact 3 LEDs that can be treated as 3 individual pixels. By rendering an image 3 times the horizontal dimension of the screen and then resizing this image down to the original screen's width, and by performing some filtering magic in between we can greatly improve the anti-aliasing of the image content.

Now the author says:

> Image processing gurus would refer to this as a five-element low-pass windowing filter with coefficients of [1/9, 2/9, 3/9, 2/9, 1/9].

[image]

This is the kind of filter you need to apply when you filter the texture down from 3 times the screen width to the screen width.

My questions are:

- is it possible to specify a custom filter kernel when a texture is being resized?
- if not, could someone suggests some ideas about how could this be achieved in a fragment shader. Let's say a fragment is being shaded. I have the texture coordinate for that fragment that I can use to read a texel from the texture. How can I use this with the derivative of the texture coordinate in order to potentially access the right neighbour pixels and average their contribution? Is something like that possible?

Any reference to either technique would be greatly appreciated.

PS:

Right now my pipeline is as follows:

- I render the content with a width a 3 * screen width x 1 * screen height to a texture
- I apply the texture to a quad that fills the screen

Comment: Being x,y the fragment coords, you can sample three times with x-1, x, x+1 and do the "blending" on your own. I suppose your shader executes "width x height" times (without 3*)

Comment: @ripi2 yes that sounds reasonable. I guess I can simplify the math by setting the texture coordinates to be in the range `[0:width*3]` do as many lookups as I want and then average. That seems pretty simple in fact. I will give it a go and post an edit if the solution works.